# Node.js + Mongoose - Not getting data every time

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I made a drop-down which gets its links from some data I get with mongoose.

However its not persistent. With the exact same code, I don't always get my data for the links.

(It's like this for all my things actually, but my drop-downs are simple)

My drop-down (made with EJS and bootstrap)

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navdrop">
                        <% schools.forEach((school) => { %>
                            <a href="/skoler/<%= school.adress.city %>" class="dropdown-item"><%= school.name %></a>
                        <% }); %>
                    </div>
```

(Sorry for the shitty format above, the editor wouldnt let me make it better).

This is my route for handling my index page.

```
server.get('/', 
    async function(req, res) {
        let schools = await schoolService.getAll();

        res.render('public assets/pages/index', {
            page_title: "Langaming.dk - Index",
            schools: schools
        });
    }
);
```

This is my schoolService.getAll();

```
"getAll": () => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        School.find({}, function (err, schools) {
            if (err)
                return reject(err)
            else 
                return resolve(schools)
        });
    })
}
```

I will try and explain it a bit better. When I go onto my page, sometimes the links show up, and other times they don't. (Mostly they don't). It's the same code all the time.

The project is running express for route handling.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Might be that for some reason your database doesn't have documents (are you wiping out data between requests?) and it's not going to throw an error just because of it.

```
"getAll": () => {
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    School.find({}, function (err, schools) {

        if (err)
            return reject(err)
        if (!schools) { 
            console.log('there are no documents');
            return reject();
        }
        else 
            resolve(schools)
    });
})
```

}

Comment: I have tried to see whether or not it is receiving any schools at all. However its not recieving anything at all. (at the same time i am connected with MongoDB Compas to check my collection, and it is just fine and dandy there. 

So i havent been deleting anything from my collection.

Comment: To clarify, i added a console.log(schools) to see if i recieved any data, but it checks out as a empty array like this -> '[ ]'

And the times it does recieve the data it comes out like this -> '[ { object }, { object } ]'.

Comment: as I was dreading... looks like the database sometimes doesn't have documents and by default it will return an empty array, then it has and it's returning  the appropriate data then

Comment: I am slightly confused as to what you mean. I am observing the database while this error happens with compass and it recieves the documents just fine?