# mongoose.find() not returning every time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I already did try to post my issue once, but I didn't get any response.

My issue is that when I use Foo.find({}) it sometimes returns the data I am looking for, other times it returns a empty array like this -> [] and as a third option it some times returns Null.

I am working in a node.js project using Express.

I'll link my other Stack Overflow post for the code in the project.

[Node.js + Mongoose - Not getting data everytime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52373454/node-js-mongoose-not-getting-data-everytime)

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Node.js + Mongoose - Not getting data every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52373454/node-js-mongoose-not-getting-data-every-time)

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose [exec](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec) would give you a promise so you do not need to wrap the `find` with one. Try this:

```
"getAll": async () => await School.find({}).exec()
```

Comment: I just tried this, same thing happens tho. Its driving me nuts